# sed match part of string, but only modify certain section (or awk, if that could be simpler)

Tags: regex, awk, sed, gnu

I have a file say tmp.txt below.

```
    root:cDJZp9SHD2KhVgc:0:0:99999:7:::
    bin:*:12821:0:99999:7:::
    daemon:*:12811:0:99999:7:::
    adm:*:12811:0:99999:7:::
    lp:*:12811:0:99999:7:::
```

I want to change the first occurrence, only in the 1st line, of 0 with a '999999'. It could be the case that this file is already modified so the 1st line is like below.

```
root:cDJZp9SHD2KhVgc:999999:0:99999:7:::
```

So I am trying to match something along the lines of `'root:\w:0'`, and only modify the 0. Is there a way to match this part of a string, and indicate a certain section (in this case the 0), to only modify with sed? Or is there a better way to do it with awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed -r '1s/([a-zA-Z]:)0/\199999/' file

root:cDJZp9SHD2KhVgc:99999:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:12821:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:12811:0:99999:7:::
adm:*:12811:0:99999:7:::
lp:*:12811:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response @karakfa. Can you explain what the -r option does? Documentation just says "use extended regular expressions in the script".

Comment: for regex, namely for grouping and `\1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the third field in the first line to "999999" if and only if it is exactly equal to "0", then a simple and direct way to do so would be to use awk as follows:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NR==1 && $3 == "0" {$3 = "999999"} {print}'
```

The same can be achieved using sed but it's not quite as simple or readable.

(Another advantage of awk here is not having to deal with the non-standard nature of the -r/-E option of sed.)